# I am unable to fill the entire screen with this element?

Tags: html, css, typescript, next.js, tailwind-css

```
import Header from "@/components/Header"
import ListItem from "@/components/ListItem"

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div className="
    bg-neutral-900
    rounded-lg
    h-100%
    w-100%
    overflow-hidden
    overflow-y-au
    ">
      <Header>
        
        <div className="mb-2">
          <h1 className="
          text-white
          text-3xl
          font-bold
          ">
            Welcome Back!
          </h1>
          <div className="
          grid
          grid-cols-1
          sm:grid-cols-2
          xl:grid-cols-3
          2xl:grid-cols-4
          gap-3
          mt-4
          ">
            <ListItem
            image="/images/liked.png"
            name="Liked Songs"
            href="Liked"
            
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </Header>
      <div className="mt-2 mb-7 px-6">
        <div className="flex justify-between items-center">
          <h1 className="text-white text-2xl font-bold">
            New Realeases
          </h1>
        </div>
        <div>
          List of Songs
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

This is the code and this is what I am getting

[image]

I tried almost everything at this point, there's no particular error as such I'm clueless how to move forward

Comment: Could you elaborate more on what you mean by "this element" please?

Comment: The background box which is bot filling the entire screen

Comment: The right part pf the screen is blank

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't quite understand. Which is the background box in your provided code please? I don't see any mention of "bot" in it.

Comment: Umm the first className in the return function is the one acting as the background box if that helps.

Comment: Try applying `height: 100vw; width: 100vw` via `h-screen w-screen` classes respectively.